# .htaccess rewrite url to main domain from subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain like: 
this.that.com
(it can also be accessed from:)
that.com/this

What I would like to do is make it so that the server transfers all requests from the two above url's to:
this.com

I need it so if I type in this.that.com
it will auto transfer to this.com

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you also want `that.com/this` to be redirected to `this.com`? Your question implies as much.

Comment: I need that, however the website is in the same folder.

Comment: So if a user enters, `http://that.this.com/abc` what is the end result he sees in his browser?  And if a user enters `http://this.com/that/abc` what is the end result?

Comment: both of them will give the user the same page, as well as if they go to that.com/abc  i need it so that if they are on this.com and in the folder, it will change the url to that.com -- In other words if the url contains this, then redirect to that.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect all requests to `this.com`, match everything, which is not already `this.com`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^this\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://this.com/$0 [R,L]
```

If you want to redirect to the main page instead, leave out the URL path

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^this\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://this.com/ [R,L]
```

If everything works as expected, you can switch to `R=301` redirection.

Comment: the domain this.com is till in the same folder. I need to just change the url if it is not this.com

Comment: This is how I am doing it in PHP but there mustbe an easy way in .htaccess as well...
<?php
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'this.net'){

header("location: http://this.net");
die();
}